# server cannot handle requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

client_side:

```
    <script>
        const name = localStorage['name']
        async function getUsers() {
            const page = document.querySelector('.page')
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
            for(const name in res.usersName) {
                let userDiv = document.createElement('div')
                userDiv.innerHTML = name
                userDiv.style.textAlign = "center"
                page.append(div)
            }
        }
        getUsers()
    </script>
    </script>
```

server_side:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const server = createServer(app).listen(3000)
    /*
    BODY: all of the routs 
    */
    /*this is where I get the error when I try to make a GET request to this rout
      it sends me 404 status error
    */
    app.get('users', (req, res) => {
     const usersName = new Array()
     console.log(req)
     for(const user of users) {
        usersName.push(user.name)
     }
     res.json({ usersName })
    })
```

when I make a GET request to API/users route I get this error message in the client_side console:

```
home:27 GET http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)
```

and I don't know why can anyone help

Comment: change `http://localhost:3000/users` to `http://localhost:3000/api/users` and `app.get('api/users'` to `app.get('/api/users'`

Comment: [The `localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is pretty specific as to how to use it.

Comment: no I did that I just made that mistake because I rewrite the code not paste it

Comment: use postman to test a get to http://localhost:3000/users and share us the result

Comment: its just the html of a web page saying cannot get the result in the body from postman:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot GET /users</pre>
</body>

</html>
somehow the /users rout does not exist, it may be a bug in Expressjs

Comment: Is there a sever actually listening on this address and port? Please post the full server side code.

Comment: Yes please post the full server file code. Also, change **app.get("users" ...** to **app.get("/users"....**

Comment: XD I just forgot / sorry for this dumb question am new to backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to put `/` before `users'.

```
app.get('/users', (req, res)=>{
    //your code block here
})
```

Comment: oops, my bad sometimes as a programmer you make the dumbest mistakes